# Introducing a new line between a matched pattern in sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have a file in which some patterns are like: `^@^@+123^@`

I want to introduce new line character between the pattern as:

```
^@
+123^@
```

I tried `sed -i 's/\x00\x00+...\x000/\n/g' filename`.

But above line is removing searched pattern. Is there any way to keep the pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture your pattern in a group, and then re-introduce it later as a replacement before adding a newline character after it, e.g.:

```
sed -i 's/(\x00\x00+...\x00)/\1\n/g' filename
```

If you want to replace `^@` between two other `^@` characters with a new line, you can do it like:

```
sed -i 's/\(\^@[^^]*\)\^@\([^^]*\^@\)/\1\n\2/g' filename
```

Comment: I want to remove one ^@ among two of them and a new line character after that. Is it possible

Answer (score 0):

This will replace *the second* `^@` with `\n`

`sed -i 's/\^@/\n/2' filename`